# Bootstrap Pills unclickable on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my pills to work on a small screen. They can tab content fine on a normal screen, but once I make the screen small, the pills are unclickable.

I don't know what the problem is.

Also if I have only the pills, then it tabs but once it's in the container, then it doesn't tab.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em; border: 2px dashed lightgreen">

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center; border: 2px dotted purple"><img src="/images/video-thumbnails/ice.jpg" class="songThumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 2px dotted purple">
                       TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin: 1em;">
                        <img src="/images/icons/piapro.png" class="favicon"> <a href="http://piapro.jp/t/O28F">ice - オケ</a> <span class="whisper">(karaoke)</span>
                    </div></div>

            </div><div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid red; float: right;">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#niconico">Niconico</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#youtube">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#soundcloud">SoundCloud</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content" style="text-align:center;">
                    <div id="niconico" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <p><div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" ><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ext.nicovideo.jp/thumb_watch/sm28116292"></script><noscript><a href="http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm28116292">【ニコニコ動画】【Faeri】ice【歌ってみた】</a></noscript>
                        </div></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="youtube" class="tab-pane fade">
                          <br>
                            <strong>日本語 | Japanese</strong><br>
                          <br>
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JOd9cunyWAg"></iframe>
                            </div>
                          <br>
                          <strong>英語 | English</strong><br>
                          <br>
                          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mCkHvttcSoE"></iframe>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="soundcloud" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="100%" height="600" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/244661025&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: That's odd, the pill buttons seem to work all the way down to the xs breakpoint in this Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/dFxI4rvdAm Any other details/code that may be contributing to this?

Comment: Can you post a url or perhaps a jsfiddle or codepen of your code causing the issue? I reckon you have a z-index/layering issue happening, where at smaller viewport width you have a div covering up the pills.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I've added the entire page of code to jfiddle, hope this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/FaeriMagic/37axersf/

Comment: Hi sorry none of your css is there...to see overlapping divs, use Web Developer tools in Firefox or Chrome and run Outline/Outline Block Level Elements then squish your browser smaller widthwise to see what containers are blocking your pills.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I didn't use much extra CSS, but I've updated the link to include it. 
Nothing seems to be blocking the pills; I can see the pill text clearly. What strange is that when refreshing the page, the pills are tabbable on a small screen for a few split seconds, but once the video embed loads, I can't tab them.

Answer (score 0):

After re-implementing the page again and fiddling around with the columns/rows, I realized that it *was* a case of z-index. Oops. It wasn't obvious until I changed the bg color of the divs.

The final code I ended up with for the media sidebar was this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 pull-right" style="background-color: #99CCFF; border: 3px dotted red; display: block; z-index: 1; margin-top: 1em;">
            <!-- All that jazz and other stuff -->

        </div>
```

And it seems to work like I wanted to. Hopefully it won't hiccup on me in the future. @NathanielFlick, apologies for not being more helpful in providing the code, but I really appreciate you taking the time to respond back to me. Thanks!